# How can I split a data into small datasets by rows?

Tags: python, dataframe, split, dataset, rows

I have a dataset of 60000x32. I want to split it like that
 first split= (0:126,:)
 second=(126:252,:)
`  third= (252:378,:)
..
.. till the end...

It should be in that order. Every split needs to be in the size of 126x32. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried slicing with loc on the dataframe

Comment: I know that but there are about 480 splits. I am looking for a quick way.

Comment: you can setup the splits segment ranges as tuples in a list then programmatic separate the data.  creating the tuple is a offset of the size 126x32

Comment: is the dataset an list of a list with 32 items per list

Comment: the dataset is a dataframe consisting of 60000 rows and 32 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
def segment_data(data, n_rows):
    """
    :param data: dataframe with 60000 rows and 32 features
    :param n_rows: number of rows in each segment
    :return: list of dataframes with 126 rows and 32 features
    """
    segments = []
    for i in range(0, len(data), n_rows):
        segment = data.iloc[i:i + n_rows, :]
        segments.append(segment)
    return segments


segments = segment_data(data, 126)
```